# KeyError on indexing a dataframe on an index that should exist

Tags: python, pandas, time-series, standardization

This is basically just me trying to normalize my data so my model performs better. It worked without but I am trying things out to improve performance. It is a timeseries in a LSTM so has to be sequenced which works perfectly fine as well as the first block of code below that is separating my data into train test split based on year.

```
test = {}
tracks = incident_data["geoid10"].unique().tolist()
train_x, train_y = creatsequence(
    incident_data[incident_data["geoid10"] == tracks[0]], 4
)
tracks.pop(0)
for track in tracks:
    test_data = incident_data[incident_data["geoid10"] == track]
    if test_data[test_data["Year"] < 2016].shape[0] > 4:
        trainx, trainy = creatsequence(test_data[test_data["Year"] < 2016], 4)
        train_x = np.concatenate((train_x, trainx))
        train_y = np.concatenate((train_y, trainy))
        if test_data[test_data["Year"] >= 2015].shape[0] > 4:
            test_x, test_y = creatsequence(test_data[test_data["Year"] >= 2015], 4)
            test[track] = {"X": test_x, "y": test_y}

def creatsequence(data, length):
    x = []
    y = []
    for column in ["All Other Thefts_y", "Simple Assault_y", "Theft From Motor Vehicle_y"]:
        data[column] = normalizeSeries(data[column], 4)
    for i in range(len(data) - length):
        x.append(data.drop(columns=['geoid10',
        'Year','Quarter'])[i:i+length])
        y.append(np.array(data[["All Other Thefts_y", "Simple Assault_y", "Theft From Motor Vehicle_y"]])[i+length])
        
    return(np.array(x), np.array(y))

def normalizeSeries(x, priorDays):

    new_x = []
    
    start = len(x) - 1
    while start > 0:
        print(x)
        if start - priorDays > 4:
            subarray = x[start - 2 * priorDays : start - priorDays]
        else:
            subarray = x[0:4]
            
        max_value = max([max(subarray),0.001])
        for i in range(4):
            value = x[start]
            new_x.append(value / max_value)
            start -= 1

    return new_x
```

The error:

```
KeyError: 11

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
/tmp/ipykernel_12/1047915744.py in <cell line: 11>()
     12     test_data = incident_data[incident_data["geoid10"] == track]
     13     if test_data[test_data["Year"] < 2016].shape[0] > 4:
---> 14         trainx, trainy = creatsequence(test_data[test_data["Year"] < 2016], 4)
     15         train_x = np.concatenate((train_x, trainx))
     16         train_y = np.concatenate((train_y, trainy))

/tmp/ipykernel_12/2018859376.py in creatsequence(data, length)
      8     y = []
      9     for column in ["All Other Thefts_y", "Simple Assault_y", "Theft From Motor Vehicle_y"]:
---> 10         data[column] = normalizeSeries(data[column], 4)
     11     for i in range(len(data) - length):
     12         x.append(data.drop(columns=['geoid10',

/tmp/ipykernel_12/2642226622.py in normalizeSeries(x, priorDays)
     17         max_value = max([max(subarray),0.001])
     18         for i in range(4):
---> 19             value = x[start]
     20             new_x.append(value / max_value)
     21             start -= 1

~/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/python-kernel-OtKFaj5M-py3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/series.py in __getitem__(self, key)
    979 
    980         elif key_is_scalar:
--> 981             return self._get_value(key)
    982 
    983         if is_hashable(key):

~/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/python-kernel-OtKFaj5M-py3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/series.py in _get_value(self, label, takeable)
   1087 
   1088         # Similar to Index.get_value, but we do not fall back to positional
-> 1089         loc = self.index.get_loc(label)
   1090         return self.index._get_values_for_loc(self, loc, label)
   1091 

~/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/python-kernel-OtKFaj5M-py3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   3802                 return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)
   3803             except KeyError as err:
-> 3804                 raise KeyError(key) from err
   3805             except TypeError:
   3806                 # If we have a listlike key, _check_indexing_error will raise
```

I am trying to get my data normalized the sequenced and thrown into a train test split. The first few tables work in the first track but once it hits the second it throws the index error. I checked the track and it has data and does have that length.

Answer (score 0):

You are indexing from a series using the index 11.
In this line:

```
---> 19             value = x[start]
```

The only way I can explain this is that this index exceeds the length of the pd.Series.

The fact that this works the first iteration but not the second, tells me that you are overwriting/changing some data in a meaningful way. And in fact there are variables outside the loop, for example:

```
train_x, train_y = creatsequence(
    incident_data[incident_data["geoid10"] == tracks[0]], 4
)
```

These variables are then changed in the loop:

```
train_x = np.concatenate((train_x, trainx))
train_y = np.concatenate((train_y, trainy))
```

Note, that when you are initialising these variables outside the loop they likely do NOT make a copy of the `incident_data` but you are likely returning a slice. Therefore overwriting train_x and train_y might change incident_data, thereby likely breaking this:

```
test_data = incident_data[incident_data["geoid10"] == track]
if test_data[test_data["Year"] < 2016].shape[0] > 4:
    trainx, trainy = creatsequence(test_data[test_data["Year"] < 2016], 4)
```

This is of course only based on the logic of the program as I can read it, but it is difficult to debug without the runnable example. But I would assume that your problem is somewhere along these lines.